# Download folders and subfolders from document libraries: bulk download

Tags: 2010, document-library

I have multiple folders and sub folders in a SharePoint document library.

How to download multiple folders and subfolders from this library at once?

Comment: Open with Windows Explorer, select, copy, paste?

Comment: any other way around ? i have issues with my ribbon control.

Comment: Open in SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to the document library or list.
2. Open Explorer View of the respective document library.
3. Drag & Drop the folder from library to local drive OR Select the folder -> right click -> copy, then paste it on the local drive.

Comment: I get an error about file names being too long (even though they're not very long). Is there any other way?

Comment: Issue is the length of the file names or invalid characters in file names. Rename the source files with shorter or valid names. Once you rename, you can proceed with same way.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options out of the Box.

1. You can use "Open with explorer" functionality in the Ribbon.
2. You can install SharePoint Work-Space and sync your data, bulk upload and download.

Comment: 1. I get an error about file paths being too long
2. Syncing won't work because my 40MB folder is "too big".
Is there a third way?

Answer (score 2):

Two no code, UI options are:

1. Open with Windows Explorer, select, copy, paste
2. Opening in SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 0):

Roger Cormier from Microsoft wrote some PowerShell scripts for bulk exporting documents from document libraries: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Bulk-Export-SharePoint-51857b22

Blog post about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rcormier/archive/2013/03/30/how-to-perform-bulk-downloads-of-files-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Is it possible for you to include a basic script in your post to make it less dependent on the links?

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell and use this logic. this will iterate through all subfolders. also you can download it using initials of Root Folders.

```
function ProcessAllSubfolders($folderCollection)
{
    foreach ($folder in $folderCollection)
    {
        if ($folder.Subfolders.Count -gt 0)
        {
            ProcessAllSubfolders($folder.SubFolders)
        }

        ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
    }
}

# main

foreach ($folder in $RootFolder.SubFolders)
{
    if ($folder.Name.StartsWith("a"))
    {
        if ($folder.Subfolders.Count -gt 0)
        {
            ProcessAllSubfolders($folder.SubFolders)
        }

        ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OOTB options are indeed limited to the 2 mentioned earlier. 
There are also several free SharePoint Add-ins that provide this functionality. See https://store.office.com/search.aspx?productgroup=SharePoint&qu=zip

There are many 3rd party tools (most of them commercial). See Collab365 site (https://collab365.directory/office365-sharepoint/best-sharepoint-migration-tools/). I am affiliated with one of the vendors. Their browser-based tool (no installs apart from uploading an html and javascript file) allows complete folder structures (or libraries) to be downloaded as a zip file.